# Relative paths not recognized with CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm new to C++ and I would like to use the Pytorch library in C++. The tutorial can be seen here https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html

I have an issue with my `/home/local/CLionProjects/MachineAI/CMakeLists.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(MachineAI)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libtorch)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}" )
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

This produces a lot of errors but they mostly seem to have the same problem. It's not able to find a specific file. Here's an example:

```
CMake Error at libtorch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Caffe2Config.cmake:14 (include):
  include could not find requested file:
    public/utils.cmake
```

The error is suggesting the wrong path is provided. If I take a look inside the `libtorch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Caffe2Config.cmake`, the problem line is:

```
include("public/utils.cmake")
```

It cannot find the file even though the file is located at the correct relative path `libtorch/share/cmake/Caffe2/public/utils.cmake`

If I replace the path with an absolute path, the error goes away:

```
include("/home/local/CLionProjects/MachineAI/libtorch/share/cmake/Caffe2/public/utils.cmake")
```

Here is the screenshot of relevant files for better orientation:

[image]

I would like to know if there's a way to fix the `CMakeLists.txt` file at the top so that `Caffe2Config.cmake` will be able to find the files through the relative path.

Comment: A workaround would be to manipulate `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, but the truth is that these CMake files in your libtorch installation are broken. It should be `include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/public/utils.cmake")`, and actually it's correct in libtorch source code: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/cmake/Caffe2Config.cmake.in

Comment: @SpacePotatoes you're right. Thank you very much. Looks like the link at the tutorial page gives you the broken library. I'll get it from github then.